# Why can't we pass the object of list in the adapter.insert() method?

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-adapter

I had an issue regarding `adapter.addAll()` method which I have solved already. But my confusion is still there that:

In `adapter.addAll()` I can pass the `object` of the `List` whose data type is different from `adapter` object, like this:

```
adapter.addAll(messageList);
```

But if I am doing the same through using the `adapter.insert()` method, I start getting an error, `Wrong 1st argument type. required.......`, like this:

```
adapter.insert(messageList, 0);
```

I know the problem I was facing can be solved in two ways:

**First: Add a single item from the list and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` as [Daniel Zolnai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1395437/daniel-zolnai) answered like this:**

```
int offset = 0;
for (Message message : messageList) {
    adapter.insert(message, offset++);
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

**Second: Add new items to the list and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` like this:**

```
for (int i = messageListLoad.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   messageList.add(0, messageListLoad.get(i));
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

But why can't we pass the `object` of `List` in the `adapter.insert()` method?

Answer (score 2):

There is no API for that, but that doesn't mean it can't be done.
You just have to insert your objects one-by-one:

```
int offset = 0;
for (Message message : messageList) {
    adapter.insert(message, offset++);
}
```

This will insert your list to the beginning of the existing list in your `ArrayAdapter`.

Don't forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own method in your custom adapter to pass list as an argument and assign this list to the list which is in the adapter.
Then notify the adapter. Simple!!!

Comment: Obviously, I can a create my own method for doing this. But why Android does not have an API for this?

Comment: May be because you can make your adapter to work as your requirements by making your own adapter and its methods rather than sticking to that one or few methods if given by Android API.